# How to push Allure test results to database and generate Allure dashboard by pulling test results from database

Tags: allure

We are looking for a good Automation Reporting framework for our automation test results and where we need support for multi languages (Java, Javascript, Python, Swift etc.).

Recently I came to learn that Allure is a good Automation Reporting framework where it supports for multiple languages but the only thing is it doesn’t have database support to store test results.

So we have a requirement where we need to maintain our historical test data on the database and generate dashboard by pulling those test results from database.

Could you please help me figure out how to achieve this using the Allure framework so that it fulfills my requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Allure Report has an extension system that allows you to export data and enrich reports during generation. You can create a plugin that will store all the required information into a database and replace the bundled history plugin with your own.

The other option is to use Allure EE -- the brand new product that already uses a database to store results and provides analytics and a dashboard on your results.

Comment: Is Allure EE released, Where can I see documentation and all?

Comment: Yes, it now called Allure TestOps https://qameta.io/

Comment: I gone through the documentation but didn't figure out database(mongodb/mysql) integration option, have some other storage options  Bitbucket, Jira, Gitlab e.t.c. ?

Actually I am using Allure docker service, Allure supports extension system right some how we can export test results files to DB but how to generate report on Db test results files & where to keep those reports not understanding.. Allure Reports are single page apps right, it contain lot files to server data. So how to organize these on db level without using file storage system on Allure docker server side?

Comment: Allure TestOps is a different product, with new database based backend